# Saw this old picture about 1+1=tube, but I can't seem to get the joke

Tags: surfing

Here is the picture:

[image]

The reason I asked this question under 'Sports' is because it seemed to have something to do with surfing.

Why is 1+1 equal to tube? Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: It's a joke so don't know how much we can help. Visit these reddit link [1st](https://www.reddit.com/r/OldSchoolCool/comments/4k1rnf/a_california_teacher_teaching_the_physics_of/) and [2nd](https://www.reddit.com/r/OldSchoolCool/comments/2eg6ax/my_dad_teaching_math_in_southern_california_late/) if you haven't already and ask it over there if you would like.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a joke based on the use of English language, not something inherent to sports.

Answer (score -2):

This reference is a nod to a surfer who said "a surfer and a board is equal a tube" but it's also a nod to the mathematical formula 1 + 1 = 3.

Comment: Welcome to the site! (Bienvenue!) Please note that all contributions must be in English.

Comment: Which mathematical formula says _1+1=3_? And how is _3_ related to _Tube_?